# SQL 2005 SSRS - users other than me cannot access report

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, iis, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I created a report in SQL BI Studio, and in the SQL Server 2005 configuration tools I've done all the setup.

I have enabled 'Anonymous Access' in the IIS directory security settings, but although I can access the website, no-one else can. I tried changing the setting to integrate Windows Authentication and then people could connect, but they they received a username and password box, and I don't want to give them my username and password.

Does anyone know how I can make my website accessible to people?

Comment: could you please copy and paste the exact error

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have granted any users or groups the "browse" permission in Report Manager.

Hope this helps,

Bill

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if this'll fix your problem or not.  the way i set up my reports is i create a sql login and set up the data source on the report to use the sql login, so whenever a user views a report, instead of having to explicitly add that user to the database for rights, they just connect to the database as the login.

Answer (score 0):

Create a read-only user on your database that the web page uses to log in.